# Can we write a function in Java that takes another function signature as a parameter and executes it?

Tags: java, function

I am not sure if this is possible but here is what I wanted to achieve using java.
I want to write a function in **JAVA** (say genericFunc) with another function's signature or name (lets say randomFunc) and its parameters (randomFuncParam) as parameters to genericFunc. Now the genericFunc(randomFunc, randomFuncParam) should execute randomFunc by passing in the parameters.
This is something like:

```
void randomFunc1(int randomFuncParam){
    syso(randomFuncParam-1);
}

void randomFunc2(String randomFuncParam){
    syso(randomFuncParam+"----"+randomFuncParam);
}

void genericFunc(<func and funcParam>){
//call func here with funcParam
}
```

So calling:

```
genericFunc(<randomFunc1 and 10>) should print 9
```

and

```
genericFunc(<randomFunc2 and Hello>) should print Hello----Hello
```

Comment: Since Java8 is possible.

Comment: Carlos, Any documentation on it?

Comment: Check the: Approach 5: Specify Search Criteria Code with a Lambda Expression http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html